# BOOTSTRAP does not work completely in the ASP.NET MVC5 application

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an application in ASP.NET MVC5 and when I import bootstrap into the Layout page the css does not apply well for all classes. For example, in this navbar only the css of the "nav" class is applied, the rest does not work. Mention that I installed the dependencies for bootstrap and its latest version. Any solutions? [Code Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIqhF.png)
[Web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ypEm.png)

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-start">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="../../assets/images/logo.png" style="width: 70px; height: 70px;" />
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
        <li class="nav-item mr-2">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sing In</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sing Up</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: can you please take some time and write the code here?

Comment: sorry, I put the picture with the code, but I edited the post and put it in the post as well